# Shadow Alert returns blank message

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I'm testing the alert message using robolectric but the fetched alertDialog is returning a blank message here's the test snippet:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog();
ShadowAlertDialog sAlert = shadowOf(alertDialog);
assert(sAlert.getMessage().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myFragment.getString(R.string.a_rather_boring_alert_message)));
```

Here's the code for displaying the fragment:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alert.setTitle(heading);
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
final TextView tx1 = new TextView(context);
tx1.setText(msg);
int paddingPixelSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_large);
tx1.setPadding(paddingPixelSize, paddingPixelSize, paddingPixelSize, paddingPixelSize);
tx1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tx1.setAutoLinkMask(Activity.RESULT_OK);
alert.setView(tx1);
alert.setCancelable(false);
```

The version I'm using:

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
```

Comment: Have to try show toast of tx1? Does it have string?

Comment: Are you using compat library for alert dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just like Eugen Martynov pointed out problem is with the AlertDialog.

`getLatestAlertDialog` returns `android.app.AlertDialog` where I had used `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` so `ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog` is null

This issue has been reported here. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2232

but still no fix :(

Only option is to use `android.app.AlertDialog` everywhere